# Accessing executing assembly from worker role

Tags: reflection, azure-worker-roles

I am making a worker role that makes appDomain and loads a class on that appDomain so it can execute some methods. Class that i want to load in appDomain (called Loader) is in the same dll as the worker role. when I try to load the class in appDomain using this line

```
Loader ld = (Loader)domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(Loader).FullName);
```

I get a file not found exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Calculation Node, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I suspect that the problem is of "access rights" nature.

Is there some setting that I need to enable for that worker role or something?

I have set ComVisible(true) on assembly as well as on the Loader class. This didn't help

I should mention also that I am executing the worker role on an emulator.

Thanks in advance,

Nenad Rakic

Comment: Ok, i found solution so I think it is a good idea to share it.

Before creating new appDomain, you need to create setup wich will have base directory defined and set to executing dll location, like so:

'AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
                    setup.ApplicationBase =
                        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);'

This setup is then passed to AppDomain.CreateDomain();

Comment: If that worked for you, you can answer your own question and accept that answer. It's your call.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found solution so I think it is a good idea to share it. Before creating new appDomain, you need to create setup wich will have base directory defined and set to executing dll location, like so:

> AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
>   setup.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

This setup is then passed to `AppDomain.CreateDomain();`